# How do I create a decorator that will decorate a generator function?

Tags: python, generator, decorator, wrapper, python-decorators

I need to create a decorator function that will decorate a generator function. The generator function yields question #'s to be added as a decoration. The decorator need to accept an argument that references a function. The wrapper needs to return a formatted string that is the prompt‘Question # :’ where # will be the number yielded by calling next on the generator object.

I know my code is not correct, but I have no idea how to fix it or where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated

This is what I currently have:

```
def decorator(func):

    """decorator that constructs and saves a generator object"""

    gen_object = func()

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """wrapper"""
        question = func(*args, **kwargs)
        input(f'Question {question} <movie character>: ')
        return wrapper
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. it would help if you demonstrated what you mean with code

Comment: Should the wrapped result also be a generator, or should it be an ordinary function? If it's a generator, should it yield wrapped/modified results from the original generator, or exactly what? If it's a function, should it take all the results from the generator, and then... do what, exactly? And why do you have an `input` call in your example?

Comment: Some kind of [mre] would be helpful. Please add one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple generator that yields questions like:

```
def someF():
    yield from [
        'Name a color',
        'Name an animal', 
        'Name a country'

]
```

Then you can wrap it with a decorator in such a way that it iterates through the generator and adds the details you want. If you yield the result of `input()` you can capture the input like any other generator:

```
from functools import wraps

def gen(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        g = f(*args, **kwargs)
        for num, question in enumerate(g):
            yield input(f'question #{num}: {question}: ')
    return inner
    
@gen
def someF():
    yield from [
        'Name a color', 
        'Name an animal', 
        'Name a country'
    ]

g = someF()
list(g)
```

Using it would look something like:

```
> question #0: Name a color: Blue
> question #1: Name an animal: Dog
> question #2: Name a country: Bolivia
['Blue', 'Dog', 'Bolivia']
```